# Firefox regex: SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

Tags: regex, firefox

```
this.getRelativeStrengthIndexOverrides(value, /(?<=RSI14).*?(?=Over)/g, overrides);
```

method:

```
getRelativeStrengthIndexOverrides(name: string, regex: string | RegExp, overrides: any): [] {
..
}
```

It work fine with chrome but not in firefox. I am getting error

> "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group"

Problem is with this: `?<=` in regex

I don't understand why? What is different with this regex in chrome and FF.  If I am checking this page, then it should work in firefox too.

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/

Comment: Can you give an example of the string you are searching in

Comment: The regex engine in  Firefox does not support lookbehind.  This **has** been implemented in chrome.  Sometimes you can use capturing groups to get what you need. And your linked compatibility page shows it does NOT work in FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookbehinds (`(?<=RSI14)` in your example) are not supported by Firefox and other browsers like IE.

The compatibility of lookbehinds is shown here https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind.

You could use capturing groups like this example below. The `$1` to 3 represent the groups and they've outputted here with underscores between, but you can do whatever you want.

```js
text = "RSI14###Over"
pattern = /(RSI14)(.*?)(Over)/
$('body').html(text.replace(pattern, "$1_$2_$3"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
```